# Injection Constructor Dependency Injection with parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to understand how do I resolve multiple parameters being passed to a constructor from a DI container.

I have an interface IDataAccess (#1) and a class called SQL implementing IDataAccess (#2).
Another class ObjectBroker (#3) that supplies the Instance of any concrete class that implements interface.
I am using unity container for constructor dependency injection as shown in (#4).

All this works well, until I try to add more parameters to the  ObjectBorker constructor.
For example if I do this --> public ObjectBroker(IDataAccess da, string s), then I am not able to understand how do I resolve the parameters for the DI container?

```
    //region #1  
    public interface IDataAccess
    {
        string GetDataBaseName();
    }
    //endregion


    //region #2  
    public class SQL : IDataAccess 
    {

        public string GetDataBaseName()
        {
            return "Data retrieved from SQL, Microsoft";
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region #3  
    public class ObjectBroker 
    {
        private IDataAccess dataAccess;
        
        public ObjectBroker(IDataAccess da)  //Fails if I have public ObjectBroker(IDataAccess da, string s)
        {
            dataAccess = da;
        }
        public string GetDataBaseName()
        {
            return dataAccess.GetDataBaseName();
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region #4 
    IUnityContainer iuContainer3 = new UnityContainer();            
    iuContainer3.RegisterType<IDataAccess, SQL>("SQL");

    var con = new InjectionConstructor(iuContainer3.Resolve<IDataAccess>("SQL"));
    iuContainer3.RegisterType<BusinessFactory>("SQL", con);
    //endregion
```

Tried this
var con = new InjectionConstructor(iuContainer3.Resolve(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("da", "SQL"), new ParameterOverride("s", "PSQL") }));

But getting an error Unity.ResolutionFailedException: 'Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type DependencyInjection.IDataAccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [`InjectionConstructor`](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.Injection.InjectionConstructor.html):

```
var con = new InjectionConstructor(iuContainer3.Resolve<IDataAccess>("SQL"), "PSQL");
iuContainer3.RegisterType<ObjectBroker>("SQL", con);
```

`InjectionConstructor` instantiated with two parameters:

- `iuContainer3.Resolve<IDataAccess>("SQL")` which will be mapped to `da` constructor parameter.
- `PSQL` which will be mapped to `s` constructor parameter.

Here is [an interactive full example](https://replit.com/@VadimMartynov/InjectionConstructor-example-75437181?v=1#main.cs).

Solution using [`InjectionFactory`](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.Injection.InjectionFactory.html):

```
iuContainer3.RegisterType<ObjectBroker>("SQL", new InjectionFactory(CreateDataAccessLayer));

private static IDataAccess CreateDataBaseLayer(IUnityContainer container)
{
    var da = container.Resolve<IDataAccess>();
    return new ObjectBroker(da, "PSQL");
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, my goal is to achieve something like this...ObjectBroker bSQL3 = iuContainer3.Resolve<ObjectBroker>("SQL");
            Console.WriteLine($"Requested company name is {bSQL3.GetDataBaseName()}");  so that it prints the output. But when I use your first solution I am not able to resolve and I still get the same runtime error

Comment: @PrasanthSarath well I can't reproduce your behavior. It works fine inside the repl: https://replit.com/@VadimMartynov/WhirlwindHumbleSystemintegrator#main.cs

Comment: Fantastic! I saw the Interactive example and it worked like a charm. Wonderful, thanks for not only solving my problem but you have given the interactive example that helped me a lot, thank you so much